# Permissions on a specific List column

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, column

In a SharePoint list can I add permissions to a specific column , for some users this column should appear and hide for users those not have permissions.

Answer (score 2):

**Can I add permissions to a specific column ?**

Unfortunately **no** , SharePoint isn’t providing **column-level security** as OOTB solution for a performance reason.

But there's some workaround solution that can help you to manage permission  on list column scope as the following :

- You can deploy the [sp2013columnpermission](https://sp2013columnpermission.codeplex.com/) codplex solution for free
- You can purchase the [Infowise](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListPro) or [Design SharePoint forms](http://spform.com/) tools.
- You can use a `SPServices` to hide a specific column based on user group  in your New / Edit / Display page , by adding the following code to `Script editor`.

**[Code]**

```
<!-- jQuery Reference. You can refer it from Layouts Folder/Doc Library too, after uploading the script. -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Download SPServices from: http://spservices.codeplex.com/ Or use this CDN  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

   //If the current User does belong to the group "Service desk Operators"
    if (xml.search('GroupName') == -1)
     {
          //   alert("No, User Doesn't Exists!");                  
           $("select[title=Status]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
          //or use: $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Status")').parent().hide();
          //You can also use:  $('nobr:contains("Status")').closest('tr').hide();
       }  
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

You can define your group name at this row `xml.search('GroupName')`

Code Ref : [Hide SharePoint List Columns based on User Permissions](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/hide-sharepoint-list-columns-based-on-user-permissions.html#ixzz4PtNDMnJN)